# Intellisense for Ember injected services

Tags: ember.js, visual-studio-code, webstorm, intellisense, ember-cli

I am a bit frustrated that there doesn't seem any decent "Ember intellisense" available in any common IDE (like VS Code, Webstorm, Atom). By "intellisense" I mean that, as long as my Ember project is a standard Ember CLI project with all the common Service, Helper folders etc., and I inject e.g. a service using `myService: service()`, this would be recognized by Intellisense and, after typing `this.myService`, I would see all functions in the service. Also, if I Ctrl+Click on the function in `this.myService.myFunction()`, I would expect to navigate to the definition of myFunction.

For other frameworks, such as Angular, there are plugins which support all this.

Is it really the case that I have to use "Find in Files" to find the definition of a service function?

Does anyone know of a way or tool which I might have missed, and which would support this scenario? Note that I don't speak of bare-bones features such as switching between router/controller/template, but of real intellisense for custom objects.

Comment: are you using typescript? Angular is typescript by default, which enables a lot of type-lookup features that many editors have enabled support for by default. in ember, even though much of the framework itself is written in typescript, _using_ it is opt-in

Answer (score 3):

The situation is indeed not yet *great*. There are a couple things that do help quite a bit:

- Using TypeScript via [the ember-cli-typescript project](https://typed-ember.github.io/ember-cli-typescript) will unlock a lot of these benefits for you. (Full disclosure: I'm a maintainer.)
- There's a community-driven IntelliJ plugin which is pretty good, [intellij-emberj](https://github.com/Turbo87/intellij-emberjs/); it has a fair number of those features and it's kept up to date by a member of the Ember CLI team.
- There's a [suite of VS Code plugins](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=emberjs.emberjs), including a language server, which gives a fair bit of it.

(There's certainly a lot more to be done here, and unfortunately none of the IDE developers seem interested in providing native support themselves, so it has fallen to the community to build it all.)

Comment: I did look at ember-cli-typescript, but switching to typescript seems to be too experimental and time-consuming for my current project.There is a lot more involved than just changing the ".js" to ".ts" exentions, it seems, if I read through the articles on www.chriskrycho.com

Comment: That is indeed the case – though those posts are also in need of another round of updates!

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at various code editors and plugins that ember community suggests,
[dev tools](https://cli.emberjs.com/release/appendix/dev-tools/)

I wonder the same way as you, realising that there is no IDE have particularly good support for Ember.

I'm using Webstorm community version for the past 6 months, but I don’t think it’s the ideal EmberJS IDE. I wonder if there is an IDE which provides some kind of intellisense/code completion/helper suggestions.

Ember has always seemed to be a very IDE-like framework, so it surprises me that no-one here (ember community, IDE developers) is building any clever plugins for IDEA or Atom or VS Code.

Answer (score 0):

VS Code plugins:

[emberjs.vscode-ember](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=emberjs.vscode-ember) - Langserver for VSCode.

[lifeart.vscode-ember-unstable](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=lifeart.vscode-ember-unstable) - Unofficial Canary Version.

Comment: of course I use the ember language server for vscode (not the canary version). however, it doesn't provide "rich" intellisense for injected objects

Comment: The canary version does intellisense in templates which is neat